# convexity in the system identification problem and in the least squares method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, convex-analysis

I am currently studying a task related to system identification as part of a course at my institute. The task involves considering the ordinary differential equation:

\begin{equation} 
 \frac{d z}{dt} (t) = g(z(t), t), ~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{(GT)}
\end{equation}

where $g$ is hidden function of this dynamic process, $z(t) \in R^d$. We have  a series of observations along a single trajectory process of (GT):
$$
Y = \{ z(\tau_1), \dots, z(\tau_n) \} = \{ y_1, \dots, y_n \}. ~~~~~~\text{(SO)}
$$
Our task is to restore function $g$. Let $f(z(t), t, \theta)$ is family of approximation $g(z(t), t)$, when $\theta \in R^{k}$ is variable parameters. Consider Cauchy task for ODE:
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned}
\frac{d z_{\theta} }{dt} (t) &= f( z_{\theta}(t), t, \theta ), \\
z_{\theta} (t_0) &= z_0,
\end{aligned} \right.
$$
and define the Mean Squared Error (MSE) loss:
$$
L^2(\theta, t_0, z_0) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \| z_{\theta} (\tau_j) - y_j  \|^2 \to \min. ~~~~~~~~\text{(L)}
$$
I would like to solve (L) with using gradient descent, variable parameters is $\theta \in R^k, t_0 \in R, z_0 \in R^d$.

I believe there is literature describing such a task. I am wondering if the task (L) can be convex and what the necessary and sufficient conditions are for (L) to be convex.